# Gatsby "npm run deploy --legacy-peer-deps" throws an unclear error

Tags: npm, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

When trying to deploy my GatsbyJS website to GitHub pages with the command `npm run deploy --legacy-peer-deps`, the following output is printed (and the code is not deployed):

```
> website@1.6.0 deploy
> gatsby build && gh-pages -d public -b master

success compile gatsby files - 2.754s
success load gatsby config - 0.142s
warn Plugin gatsby-source-filesystem is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.2.0
warn Plugin gatsby-source-filesystem is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.2.0
warn Plugin gatsby-remark-reading-time is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-remark-prismjs is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-google-gtag is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-netlify is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-google-analytics is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-sass is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-react-helmet is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-sitemap is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-offline is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.4.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-styled-components is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires
gatsby@^2.0.32
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-feed is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.4.0
warn Plugin gatsby-source-filesystem is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.2.0
warn Plugin gatsby-source-filesystem is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.2.0
warn Plugin gatsby-remark-reading-time is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-remark-prismjs is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-google-gtag is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-netlify is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-google-analytics is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-sass is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-react-helmet is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-sitemap is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-offline is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.4.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-styled-components is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires
gatsby@^2.0.32
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-feed is not compatible with your gatsby version 4.25.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.4.0
success load plugins - 1.818s
success onPreInit - 0.005s
success delete worker cache from previous builds - 0.003s
success initialize cache - 0.108s
success copy gatsby files - 0.343s
success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 0.333s
success onPreBootstrap - 0.351s
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.010s
success Checking for changed pages - 0.001s
success source and transform nodes - 2.596s
info Writing GraphQL type definitions to C:/Users/Darren Dube/Documents/Projects/website/.cache/schema.gql
success building schema - 0.438s
success createPages - 0.075s
success createPagesStatefully - 0.244s
info Total nodes: 146, SitePage nodes: 20 (use --verbose for breakdown)
success Checking for changed pages - 0.001s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.001s
⠴ extract queries from components
C:\Users\Darren Dube\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\yoga-layout-prebuilt\yoga-layout\build\Release\nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error: Error in native callback
    at Sharp.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Darren Dube\Documents\Projects\website\node_modules\sharp\lib\input.js:384:17)
    at Sharp.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at finish (node:internal/streams/writable:748:10)
    at node:internal/streams/writable:726:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

Node.js v18.16.1
```

I do not understand what that error at the end means (Error in native callback ...), and how it can be fixed. What should I do?